# How to decompile ARM (iOS) to Objective-C using IDA?

Tags: ida

What are the options to decompile ARM (iOS) to Objective-C using IDA?

I've been looking into the REobjc module (https://github.com/duo-labs/idapython), but it can only handle x64 code.

Are there other plugins that may decompile the ARM?

Comment: Are you only looking for Objective-C output, and do you need it to be compilable? Or would you accept anything that resembles a higher-level language to make it easier to understand?

Comment: @knownmalware - I would also accept pseudo-like C :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hexrays [sells](https://www.hex-rays.com/cgi-bin/quote.cgi) a [decompiler plugin for IDA Pro](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/decompiler/index.shtml).  If you have a supported (purchased or renewed within the last year) version of IDA Pro, then you can purchase one of the ARM decompiler plugins.

I have not tried the following, but have heard of them (so add a comment about how well it works if you do try one!)...

There's the opensource [snowman decompiler](https://github.com/yegord/snowman).  It has been around for a few years now.  Its website says it supports ARM and is available for radare2, x64dbg, multiple versions of IDA Pro, and as a standalone application.

Another opensource one is [RetDec](https://github.com/avast-tl/retdec).  Looks like it was just released late last year, but is from a well regarded AV company (Avast) and supposedly has been in development and use privately for several years.

I've also heard of the commercial [Hopper](https://www.hopperapp.com/) product, which specializes in macOS executables, but not sure how good the built-in decompiler is.

Comment: Awesome answer - which one would you recommend?

Comment: I'd try both of the free ones first (snowman and RetDec).  The Hexrays decompiler is pretty good, but expensive.  I also just heard that [NSA is opensourcing a disassembler/decompiler at RSAConference](https://www.rsaconference.com/events/us19/agenda/sessions/16608-Come-Get-Your-Free-NSA-Reverse-Engineering-Tool) in early March.